# WEBDAV java library to connect Exchange server 2007

Tags: java, .net, outlook, webdav, exchange-server-2007

Is there any Webdav open source java library for connecting exchange 2007 to access mail, calendar and contacts (Must use httpclient 4.*)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a library using WebDAV, however, if you can guarantee at least Exchange 2007, SP1 Microsoft put out a Java wrapper for Exchange Web Services (a more functional SOAP based interface).

You can find it at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

Edit: actually just noticed I'm using httpclient 3.1 with it... not 4... might not suit your usecase...

Comment: FWIW, EWS works very well.  In practically no time I whipped up a quick add-on to an app that pokes calendar events into Exchange.